# "Probabilities are the ghosts of quantum mechanical amplitudes"

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, probability, popular-science, born-rule

I came across this quote today;

> [Quantum computers] process information using quantum mechanical amplitudes. And probabilities are sort of the ghosts of amplitudes after they have been degraded to our mere classical world.

- [Michael Freedman on quantum computing research](https://youtu.be/l6xMb9OEhO4?t=397), circa 2015

Can someone explain what is meant by 'probabilities are the ghosts of quantum mechanical amplitudes' to me? Does this refer to amplitudes having some additional mathematical structure that probabilities do not possess? Links to more information / reading would be highly appreciated! Assume I have a high-school level understanding of quantum physics only :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Amplitudes are, in general, complex numbers. A process with amplitude $A$ has a probability $|A|^2=AA^*$ of occurring (where $A^*$ is the complex conjugate of $A$), so probabilities are positive real numbers.

This means that there are infinitely many different amplitudes that can give rise to the same probability. In particular, if we decompose $A$ into its magnitude and phase $A=re^{i\theta}$, then you can see that $|A|^2=r^2$, no matter what the value of $\theta$ is, since $|e^{i\theta}|^2=e^{i\theta}e^{-i\theta}=1$. We effectively "lose information" when going from amplitudes to probabilities. And it's precisely this extra phase information that gives rise to many of quantum mechanics's most interesting effects.

Comment: _We effectively "lose information" when going from amplitudes to probabilities._ This needs to be qualified. You don't lose any information if you consider probabilities for a tomographically complete set of observables.

Comment: @DvijD.C. Even a tomographically complete set of observables will not be able to capture the overall phase of a state. I know that that piece of information has no bearing on the actual physics, but it's lost nonetheless.

Comment: No, it is not because it wasn't there, to begin with. The overall phase is never known even when you choose to write things as probability amplitudes because it is meaningless. Overall phase is simply not a piece of any information.

Comment: @DvijD.C. The fact that it is meaningless in certain contexts does not mean that it doesn't exist. After all, the partial trace turns a relative phase into an overall phase, and there are certain situations where the overall phase of two systems affects their relative phase when considered as a single unit.

Comment: 1. The relative phase turning into an overall phase simply means that we lose information while taking a partial trace (this demonstrates my point that an overall phase doesn't carry any information). 2. Your second point is a bit hard to understand. What do you mean "considered as a single unit"? Do you mean something like "superposition of $e^{i\pi/2}|\psi\rangle$ and $|\phi\rangle$ has a different relative phase between the two components than the superposition of $e^{i\pi/4}|\psi\rangle$ and $|\phi\rangle$?

Comment: @DvijD.C. Yes, that's approximately what I was getting at.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108316/discussion-between-dvij-d-c-and-probably-someone).

Comment: @probably_someone thank you for a clear and concise explanation! Just what I was looking for!

Comment: @DvijD.C. Consider the symmetric and antisymmetric total spin-0 states of the joint system of 2 spin-1/2 particles. (I.e., triplet and singlet). If I gave you the probabilities of each product state (i.e. |spin 1, spin 2>) for the triplet and the singlet, they'd be the same. But these are very different states; thus information is indeed lost if you just look at probabilities. This is probably what OP was talking about.

Comment: ...although, when you specified quantum tomography, then thats obviously more information than I specified in my example. In which case youre probably right that you only lose an irrelevant overall phase.